# How can I echo this value?

Tags: php

All I need to do is echo array pocket $row[0].

```
while ($row = mysqli_result::fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<br>' . $row[1];
}
echo $row[0];
```

I have googled, but results haven't helped. I know I'm missing something stupid, but I'd appreciate the help!

I'm trying to echo the database column, 'ID'. An example of the data I want to echo would be '3'.

Comment: Row is not a string or an int.. it is an array.

Comment: @Daedalus What is `$row` set to since it's out of the while loop? Can you still print it?

Comment: What do you want the rendered HTML to be?

Comment: @JWH Can you post an example of your database data?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging the whole row, write this:

```
var_dump($row)
```

To output the column `ID`, write this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_result::fetch_array($result)) {
    var_dump($row); // This will output all values for each row as they're looped through
    echo '<br>' . $row['ID'];
}
var_dump($row); // dumps the last row of the returned results, or false if no rows.
echo $row['ID']; // echos the ID of the last row. However if there are no rows, this will not work.
```

Be aware, as @Daedalus pointed out, `$row` is an array, so the var_dump line is really just for debugging. Because an array has multiple values, PHP doesn't know how you want to display it. You'll need to program how each element of `$row` is displayed.

Comment: You might want to check your @s there...  I'm the one that pointed out the variable is an array.

Comment: Edited! var_dump results in a boolean (false). I know I'm missing something dead simple. Like a return.

Comment: I think it's cost $row is not set because you are after the while loop. While loop effectively says "while row is valid do stuff", so your echo is done when row is no longer valid.

Comment: False means your query returned no rows. If it did return rows, the last line of your snippet would echo the first element of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Copy $row[0] as you go.

```
$lastZero = "";
while ($row = mysqli_result::fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<br>' . $row[1];
    $lastZero = $row[0];
}
echo $lastZero;
```